# Type attributes ignored or undefined reference to phpExtension errors while compiling php-cpp main.cpp file

Tags: php, c++, g++, php-cpp

I'm using php-cpp to create an extension for my php codes and when I try to compile just the simple structure of main.cpp file, I get some weird errors.

this is the compile errors:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp
In file included from lib/phpcpp/phpcpp.h:39:0,
             from main.cpp:122:
lib/phpcpp/type.h:32:1: warning: type attributes ignored after type is already defined [-Wattributes]
 };
 ^
In file included from lib/phpcpp/phpcpp.h:60:0,
                 from main.cpp:122:
lib/phpcpp/classtype.h:31:1: warning: type attributes ignored after type is already defined [-Wattributes]
 };
 ^
/tmp/cc0tI8mp.o: In function `get_module':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::Extension(char const*, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::~Extension()'
/tmp/cc0tI8mp.o: In function `Php::Extension::operator void*()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3Php9ExtensioncvPvEv[_ZN3Php9ExtensioncvPvEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `Php::Extension::module()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

what is /tmp/cctI8mp.o ??? or the other ones?and the mentioned cctI8mp.o changes to another name each time I compile

and this is the code that I try to compile:

```
#include "lib/phpcpp/phpcpp.h"
/**
 *  tell the compiler that the get_module is a pure C function
 */
extern "C" {
    int main(){}
 PHPCPP_EXPORT void *get_module() 
    {
        static Php::Extension bias("bias_framework_free", "0.9.3.20");
        return bias;
    }
}
```

bias is the name of my extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.phpcpp.com/documentation/your-first-extension) you have to link your binary with `-lphpcpp`. The sample `Makefile` contains the following lines:

```
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o
LINKER_FLAGS        =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp
```

So to build the extension properly, the compiler/linker needs more information than you passed in your command.

Consider copying and modifying the sample `Makefile`. Note, in order to build the extension using `Makefile` you have to run `make` command(which will look for the makefiles in the current directory by default).

Comment: I have previously take cared of editing that file and my LINKER_DEPENDENCIES is:  
/home/WorkSpace/PHP-CPP/libphpcpp.so.1.5.2

Comment: @Amir, I clearly see that you haven't taken care of the link flags, at least: `g++ -std=gnu++11 main.cpp`. And the output in your post contains errors regarding the object files, so it's about the link phase. Also try `make clean && make`

Comment: Thanks for ur time, but I think I'm not getting some parts of what you want to say.
These are the three lines that you mentioned, in my make file in the extension directory:

`COMPILER_FLAGS  = -Wall -c -O2 -std=gnu++11 -fPIC -o
LINKER_FLAGS  = -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES = /usr/lib/libphpcpp.so` which part should I edit in these lines? I edited the LINKER_DEPENDENCES. anything more to do?

Comment: And sth else, each time I want to compile with g++ command, I add the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 to the command line.

Comment: @Amir, do you run `g++` command manually? You should only run `make` within the directory with `Makefile`.

Comment: For the first time compiling I used `make` command and after that I just want to compile the `main.cpp`, and for this I use `g++` command.

Comment: @Amir, you shouldn't invoke `g++` directly! Use makefile instead. If `main.cpp` is supposed to be a part of the project, then tweak `Makefile` accordingly.